# Is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video in BlueJeans for iOS?

Tags: ios

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on iOS 11. When in a videoconference, is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video?

The motivation is to reduce the network usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swipe up, which will activate the "low bandwidth" mode:

[image]

Swipe down to go back to the normal mode.